# Calculating if item was sold in 24h

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two columns with **item list date** and **item sold date** in dataframe.
Need ideas how to calculate if an item was sold in 24hours.
Results should be in new column - sold_in_24 and be True/False, better 1/0.

| list_date | sold_date | sold_in_24 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-09-30 19:06:21 | 2018-09-30 23:06:21 | 1 |
| 2018-07-08 15:02:32 | 2018-07-24 19:02:32 | 0 |
| 2018-07-08 19:02:32 | 2018-07-09 15:02:32 | 1 |

What comes to my mind is:
df['sold_in_24'] = [df.sold_date - df.list_date for x in df['sold_in_24'] if x <= 24]

Comment: So what's your problem? Does the thing that came to your mind not work?

Comment: Cant find a way to do it. The method does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are [`datetime64[ns]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) type, you can subtract them and check if the difference is less than 24 hours:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67246707/calculating-if-item-was-sold-in-24h")[0]
df["list_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["list_date"])
df["sold_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["sold_date"])

df["was_sold_in_24h"] = (df["sold_date"] - df["list_date"]) < pd.Timedelta(days=1)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
            list_date           sold_date  sold_in_24
0 2018-09-30 19:06:21 2018-09-30 23:06:21        True
1 2018-07-08 15:02:32 2018-07-24 19:02:32       False
2 2018-07-08 19:02:32 2018-07-09 15:02:32        True
```